# Lip moving on lip plate while playing

Tags: flute

My lip tends to move around a little bit on the lip plate when playing the flute when playing fast passages, so the quality of the notes is sometimes not very good for those fast passages.

Is there some good way to correct this?

Comment: Do you have a teacher? Having an outside observer is critical to eliminating bad habits.   And the old stand-by advice: play it slowly, and speed up only so far as you can do while NOT collapsing your embouchure. Then speed up step-by-step.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to keep your posture correct, as you might not be holding up your arms high enough so the flute is horizontal (putting enough vertical pressure to your lips with your flute).

Also clean your mouthpiece and make sure it is not oily or slippery. Cleaning it with a silver clean cloth is good for the silver, but might leave some oily residue. The same with your chin, make sure your skin is not oily.

And lastly: just picture that the bottom of your lip is glued to your flute. Open your mouth and keep the flute stuck to your lip, move around a bit and see the flute stays in position.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this just happens especially if you are nervous or just happen to be kind of sweaty.  A lot of flutist have an engraved lip plate myself included which gives you a bit more grip.

An interim solution is using a small piece of tape, I just used scotch tape some people use surgical tape but I didn't like it.  I have also seen special stickies sold for this in music stores but they didn't seem worth the price.

Many people find that after using tape for a while the problem goes away so I suggest when it comes time to change the tape (you will know) try playing without it (clean the mouth piece of any sticky residue first) and see if things have improved.

No pun intended but don't sweat it, many players use something to help with this their entire career.

BTW the totally horizontal flute position fetish that has crept up fairly recently is really not that good an idea unless you are in a marching band.  The flute needs to be parallel to your lips not the floor.  Tilting your head slightly so the flute tilts down is usually a lot more comfortable and in the long run reduces the stress on your arms and shoulder,.  NOTE:  I said slightly, tilting too much just moves the strain to your neck.

At best flute is a very awkward instrument to play with its horizontal position so slight adjustments to accommodate your body should be made whenever possible.  Not everyone has the same length arms, fingers, neck etc.